# Are there eigenvalues of random matrices?

Tags: probability-theory

Suppose $A$ in $\mathbb{C}^{M\times M}$ is a  matrix of random variables. Can we define a concept similar to eigenvalues for $A$?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know exactly what you're expecting, but did you look at the Wikipedia entry on random matrices, and the references therein? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_matrix

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For every $\omega \in \Omega$ we have that $A(\omega)$ is an $M\times M$ complex matrix. Thus it has eigenvalues etc. One interesting thing to do would be to denote (with multiplicity) the generalized eigenvalues (of which there are exactly $M$ regardless of the matrix) and order them from smallest to largest $\lambda_{(1)},\ldots,\lambda_{(M)}$, and maybe you want to let $N(\omega)$ count how many of them are true eigenvalues (not generalized eigenvalues). Now $N$ and each of the $\lambda_{(i)}$ are a random variables and so you can do your usual things and ask questions about their (joint) distributions. If you read the references on the Wikipedia page I'm sure you will find some interesting theorems on these things.